# Paper trail version history unexpectedly contains record not matching conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, versioning, paper-trail-gem

As per [this Readme section](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#2b-choosing-when-to-save-new-versions), I specify that I only want my record to be tracked when the following conditional is met:

```rb
has_paper_trail only: [:body], if: Proc.new { |p| !p.draft }
```

This code is in my Post model. In other words, I only want versioning for posts that are not drafts.

To my surprise, changing a post from draft to non-draft stores the draft version:

```
> Post.last.update body: 'bar', draft: false
> Post.last.versions.count
 => 1
> Post.last.versions.last.reify
 => #<Post id: 274, body: "foo", draft: true ...>
                                        ^
```

I don't want to track draft posts. My impression is that the draft version should not be stored since it does not meet my conditional. I would have expected versioning to start *after* the conditional is met, not before.

Or am I misunderstanding something or using the gem wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior makes kind of sense to me because when the status changed from `draft` to something else then the status is at the time of saving the record not `draft` anymore and therefore the previous version will be stored.

If you do not want to store the last draft version then you need to change your condition to this

```
has_paper_trail only: [:body], if: Proc.new { |p| !p.draft && !p.draft_was }
```

or this

```
has_paper_trail only: [:body], if: Proc.new { |p| !p.draft && !p.draft_previously_was }
```

`draft_was` and `draft_previously_was` are methods generated by [`ActiveModel::Dirty`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).

Both – dirty attributes and paper trail – are called and running during the phase after a record was saved into the database and the database change was committed. Depending on which runs first `draft_was` still might be set when paper trail checks the condition or `draft_was` might already be reset but then `draft_previously_was` should be set instead.

Comment: I think it's `draft_was`. In any case, it still stores a record with `draft` set to `true`. At first I thought you had to be right since [here](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail#choosing-based-on-changed-attributes) it says "versions are saved during an after-callback. If you decide whether to save a new version based on changed attributes, use attribute_name_was instead of attribute_name." Now I'm wondering what difference using `_was` can make since I believe `save` will reset `draft_was` to the value of `draft` anyway and the proc only runs after `save` runs.

Comment: You are right, it is `draft_was`. I fixed that in my answer. Because both – Dirty and PaperTrail - are run during the after-callbacks it depends on the order in which they are running. I updated my answer to address that. If the version with the `darft_was` doesn't work for you, you might want to try `draft_previously_was` instead or even both to be sure that it still works even if the running order of Dirty and PaperTrail in the callback chain is not stable.

Comment: The thing is, `draft_previously_was` is also set after save – presumably – and so it seems just as unreliable as `draft_was`. Any value either of these two methods return *could* be true. I see there's also `[draft_before_last_save](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Dirty.html#method-i-attribute_before_last_save)` – which sounds more specific and exact in what it refers to so I'll try that one. In any case, the fact that Dirty and paper trail can run out of order seems like something the paper trail folks should acknowledge in the Readme...

Comment: In any case, since we have moved on to a different question and you've answered the original one, I'll accept your answer.